# React Table SubComponent Return Another Table

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, react-table

I have the below React Table that I have data in the main table and if you click on any arrows, I display another table under that row. The problem is based on which row you click, I need to make an API request, get the data, then display. The problem is return inside the `this.getDetail` doesn't make a visual change on the SubComponent. `console.log(result)` do print out the correct array that fetched from the API. I already set up `this.getDetail` in async-await and I am working with the promise to get the data. How can I fix it so the data I fetched gets displayed? Below subcomponent just returns 1

```
<ReactTable
  data={dataArray}
  columns={columns}
  defaultPageSize={5}
  noDataText="No Data"
  SubComponent={row => {
    this.getDetail(
      row.original.cusip,
      row.original.description,
      detailColumns
    ).then(function(result) {
      console.log(result);
      return (
        <ReactTable
          defaultPageSize={5}
          noDataText="No Data"
          columns={detailColumns}
          // data={Array.from(myDetail)}
          //resolveData={data => console.log(data)}
          //style={{ height: "400px" }}
          //showPagination={false}
        />
      );
    });
    return 1;
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to  put data in state. And once your API request respond, set response in state.

So your ReactTable code will be like this

```
<ReactTable
  data={this.state.dataArray}
  ...
  .../>
```

So when state is updated via `this.setState({ dataArray: apiResonse });` your ReactTable will render.

Comment: thank you but that won't work, here's why. So lets say first row, I clicked the arrow, I got the data and displayed. While that row is displaying child data, I clicked on second row, then first row data will be empty while I am fetching the second row...

Comment: You should keep all row information intact in state, subrow data should be added as a new key under each row. So in your case, once you fetch sub rows of row1 it will be stored in state, again when u fetch row2 subtable data it will be added as a new key under row2 in state. This way you will have data for all subtables which u have clicked. @Extelliqent

Comment: It still doesn't render because by the time I set the data, it already had gone thru the react table code so it crashes saying data provided is undefined. React Table doesn't wait the query to come back...

Comment: Did u set the response data in state. If state is updated ReactTable will re-render with updated data.